# compare multiple columns and create count of matches

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset with ID numbers for respondents' friends and bullies.

I'd like to go through all the friendship nominations and all the bully nominations in each row and get a count of the number of people they nominate as both. Any help would be great!

HAVE DATA:

```
ID  friend_1  friend_2  friend_3  bully_1  bully_2
1          4        12         7       12       15
2          8         6         7       18       20
3          9        18         1        2        1
4         15         7         2        7       13 
5          1        17         9       17        1
6          9        19        20       14       12
7         19        12        20        9       12
8          7         1        16        2       15 
9          1        10        12        1        7
10         7        11         9       11        7
```

WANT DATA:

```
ID  friend_1  friend_2  friend_3  bully_1  bully_2  num_both
1          4        12         7       12       15         1
2          8         6         7       18       20         0
3          9        18         1        2        1         1
4         15         7         2        7       13         1
5          1        17         9       17        1         2
6          9        19        20       14       12         0
7         19        12        20        9       12         1
8          7         1        16        2       15         0
9          1        10        12        1        7         1
10         7        11         9       11        7         2
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `apply` row-wise and find out the the number of common friends which are present both in `friend` and `bully` columns

```
df$num_both <- apply(df, 1, function(x) 
      length(intersect(x[grep("friend", names(df))], x[grep("bully", names(df))])))


#   ID friend_1 friend_2 friend_3 bully_1 bully_2 num_both
#1   1        4       12        7      12      15        1
#2   2        8        6        7      18      20        0
#3   3        9       18        1       2       1        1
#4   4       15        7        2       7      13        1
#5   5        1       17        9      17       1        2
#6   6        9       19       20      14      12        0
#7   7       19       12       20       9      12        1
#8   8        7        1       16       2      15        0
#9   9        1       10       12       1       7        1
#10 10        7       11        9      11       7        2
```

---

Or if you are not a big fan of `apply`, you can use `sapply` with the same logic

```
friend_cols <- grep("friend", names(df))
bully_cols <- grep("bully", names(df))

sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) 
 length(intersect(df[i, friend_cols, drop = TRUE], df[i, bully_cols, drop = TRUE])))

#[1] 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 0 1 2
```

---

**EDIT**

If there are some `NA` values and we want to exclude them we can use `is.na` and `sum`

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(intersect(x[friend_cols], x[bully_cols]))))
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I think the apply version is almost there, but it is counting the NA's in rows where the some of the observations have less nomination than others. Any idea how can I make sure the NA's are ignored when counting matches?

Comment: we can use `sum` and `is.na` to ignore `NA` matches. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that values are unique within friend/bully groups, a simple approach would be:

```
apply(df[,-1], 1, function (x) sum(table(x) > 1)) 
[1] 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try comparing each `bully` column with the friends columns and then taking the union to compute a matrix of matches. To get your `num_both` you simply `rowSum` this match matrix:

```
bully_cols <- grep("bully", names(df))
friend_cols <- grep("friend", names(df))
df$num_both <- rowSums(Reduce("|", lapply(df[,bully_cols], function(x, compare) compare == x, compare = df[,friend_cols])))
```

The `lapply` calculates the matches for each bully column and then the `Reduce` combines them into one matrix to be summed over the rows.

```
#   ID friend_1 friend_2 friend_3 bully_1 bully_2 num_both
#1   1        4       12        7      12      15        1
#2   2        8        6        7      18      20        0
#3   3        9       18        1       2       1        1
#4   4       15        7        2       7      13        1
#5   5        1       17        9      17       1        2
#6   6        9       19       20      14      12        0
#7   7       19       12       20       9      12        1
#8   8        7        1       16       2      15        0
#9   9        1       10       12       1       7        1
#10 10        7       11        9      11       7        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `melt` based approach from `data.table`.  We `melt` into 'long' format based on the `patterns` in the column names (start with `friend`, `bully`), grouped by 'ID', get the `length` of `intersect`ing elements of long dataset columns 'value1', 'value2' and do a join `on` the 'ID'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[melt(df1, measure = patterns('^friend', '^bully'))[,
   .(num_both = length(intersect(value1, value2))), ID], on = .(ID)]
#    ID friend_1 friend_2 friend_3 bully_1 bully_2 num_both
# 1:  1        4       12        7      12      15        1
# 2:  2        8        6        7      18      20        0
# 3:  3        9       18        1       2       1        1
# 4:  4       15        7        2       7      13        1
# 5:  5        1       17        9      17       1        2
# 6:  6        9       19       20      14      12        0
# 7:  7       19       12       20       9      12        1
# 8:  8        7        1       16       2      15        0
# 9:  9        1       10       12       1       7        1
#10: 10        7       11        9      11       7        2
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` by `gather`ing into 'long' format, grouped by 'ID', `summarise` with the `length` of `intersect`ing elements of 'value' based on the occurrence of 'friend' or 'bully' in the 'key' column and `right_join` with the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   gather(key, value, -ID) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(num_both = length(intersect(value[str_detect(key, 'friend')], 
                         value[str_detect(key, 'bully')]))) %>% 
   right_join(df1)
# A tibble: 10 x 7
#      ID num_both friend_1 friend_2 friend_3 bully_1 bully_2
#   <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>   <int>   <int>
# 1     1        1        4       12        7      12      15
# 2     2        0        8        6        7      18      20
# 3     3        1        9       18        1       2       1
# 4     4        1       15        7        2       7      13
# 5     5        2        1       17        9      17       1
# 6     6        0        9       19       20      14      12
# 7     7        1       19       12       20       9      12
# 8     8        0        7        1       16       2      15
# 9     9        1        1       10       12       1       7
#10    10        2        7       11        9      11       7
```

or another approach by looping over rows with `pmap`

```
df1 %>% 
     mutate(num_both = pmap(.[-1], ~ c(...) %>%
                                 {length(intersect(.[1:3], .[4:5]))}))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, friend_1 = c(4L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 1L, 9L, 
19L, 7L, 1L, 7L), friend_2 = c(12L, 6L, 18L, 7L, 17L, 19L, 12L, 
1L, 10L, 11L), friend_3 = c(7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 20L, 20L, 16L, 
12L, 9L), bully_1 = c(12L, 18L, 2L, 7L, 17L, 14L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 
11L), bully_2 = c(15L, 20L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 7L, 7L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```